# Error android studio canary 3

Tags: android

Hello everyone I have a problem in android studio canary 3 layout doesn't work what is the solution for this?

ScreenShot of message display Gradle project sync failed

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tried with clean?

Comment: yes I did it ...

Comment: can you translate the error in english

Comment: this translation : 
An existing connection had to be closed by the remote host

Comment: who can help me please ??

Comment: English : Garde build daemon disappeared unexpectedly

Comment: org.gradle.daemon=false to gradle properties

Comment: can you please share your android gradle file ? and was it compiling before you upgraded to android studio 3 ?

Comment: I am just download Android studio 3 i dont upgraded

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this string

```html
"org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m" with this
"org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```